# JSON format in HTML CELL table

Tags: javascript, html, json

Folks,

I have the following requirement:

I will have a list of log lines in a HTML table, some of these lines will contain JSON strings, I want to format the JSON in table when the HTML file is loaded from disk. I have it nearly there, see JSFiddle. I just cant seem to get it formatted inside the table cell:

http://jsfiddle.net/yh7bsd51/

```
var table = document.getElementById("report");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
{
   col = row.cells[0];
   //if(innerHTML == JSON)
   col.innerHTML = (syntaxHighlight(JSON.stringify(col.innerHTML, undefined, 4)));   
}  

var s = {"Id":"124578","oId":"11","Type":"2"};
var ss = JSON.stringify(s, undefined, 4);
```

Comment: Ok, I am crudely ignoring the header by altering the start index on the for loop to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the formatting inside the cell is that you were calling `JSON.stringify` on a string, not an object. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zu7zs5b1/. Note this part:

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    col = row.cells[0];
    //if(innerHTML == JSON)
    try {
        jsn = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(col.innerHTML), undefined, 4); // <-- proper JSON str
        col.innerHTML = (syntaxHighlight(jsn));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Fail");
    }
}
```

A bit hacky, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks Hans, That's exactly what i needed, i just added a Pre to format it onto multiple lines, http://jsfiddle.net/r1fcf55e/